Prisma View gives The table `public.BalanceTransactionView` does not exist in the current database
I've followed the official documentation(https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-schema/data-model/views) of Prisma in order to fetch data from a view.
If I use $queryraw i'm able to fetch the data but when i use the client like: prisma.BalanceTransacionView.findMany() it states that the The table public.BalanceTransactionView does not exist in the current database.
I've added the view to the prisma.schema and run prisma generate so I can use the prisma client to the new generated view but when i deploy it it just gives the error above.
view BalanceTransactionView {
  id                     String   @unique
  etc...
}

I suspect that I'm missing a step to make it available when i deploy it but i didn't create a migration so didn't want to create a migration unnecessarily.
If you can through some light into it could be very nice :)
Thanks!

What does "when I deploy it" mean? You are deploying what? How do you create the view in the DB? Why DON'T you create a migration that creates the view in DB if it doesn't already exist?

Hi Perttu,
Because i didn't want to create a new migration that might or might not work with the solution.
I've actually made it work. I needed to introspect the db and then change the generated view on the prisma.schema and that made it work.
I will resolve the question.

I've made it work. I needed to introspect the db with npx prisma db pull  and then change the generated view on the prisma.schema and that made it work.
Resolving question.
